# How do I ignore all hidden properties of class being inherited using reflection?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Im having an issue where I need to get all properties from an object, then sort through the properties and send the values of certain properties to another service. Here is an example of the code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public bool B  { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 : Class1 
{
    public new bool? B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all the properties of Class2, however when using Class2.GetType().GetProperties(), the result contains B from Class2 AND Class1. This causes my issue as when looping through each property I am sending B twice, one with the default value of false since it was never set, then the other with the proper value that was set by my service. I need the result to contain B from Class2, A from Class1, and C from Class2 but ignore B from Class1 since it has been hidden with the new keyword.

I have tried looking through the binding flags I can use, but it has not helped. The closest flag I can find is the BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly flag, but that excludes A from Class1, so it will not work for me.

How would I go about ignoring the original property if it has been hidden?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you need a property that hides another one? It isn't really a good practice.

Comment: Are you only interested in getting the base class's members? If class2 had a bool C would you want that as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a LINQ query to filter out the hidden properties.

```
var allProps = typeof(Class2).GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public
);

var thePropsYouWant = 
        from p in allProps
        group p by p.Name into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DeclaringType == typeof(Class2)).First();
```

See it running here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/V5sGIs

Comment: your code won't compile and seems won't work properly. did you test it?

Comment: This (after you fix compilation error) will return you only one property (from class Class2). It looks like OP wants an `A` property from Class1 and B property from Class2

Comment: Hmm, I missed that OP wants most properties from Class1.

Comment: @AleksAndreev is correct, I cannot use that binding flag as it would exclude A from Class1. Also this is just example code to get the concept across, did not test nor compile it. Not sure if what im asking is even possible, just spent a few days looking and thought id post here as a last stand

Comment: I fixed my code to actually compile and "work". Will delete this answer and ponder a bit more.

Comment: Ok, how's this?

Comment: This works perfectly! Just converted the linq to a lamba (just because I like how it looks) and boom, exactly what I needed. I tried both solutions and they both worked, guess I just need to think a little harder. Either way thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you right you need all properties from `Class2` and all properties from `Class1` that not redefined in `Class2`

You can achive this with two calls to `GetProperties`: first select all defined in `Class2` then visit type of `Class1` and add any that missing

```
var type = typeof(Class2);
var list = new List<PropertyInfo>();
list.AddRange(type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly));

var baseType = type.BaseType;
if (baseType != null)
{
    foreach (var propertyInfo in baseType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (list.All(p => p.Name != propertyInfo.Name))
            list.Add(propertyInfo);
    }
}
```

If you print that list

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in list)
    Console.WriteLine($"From {propertyInfo.DeclaringType} > '{propertyInfo.Name}':{propertyInfo.PropertyType}");
```

You will see something like:

> From Class2 > 'B':System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]
>   From Class1 > 'A':System.String

Answer (score 0):

A simple LINQ based solution which works in a generic way for all class hierarchies:

```
   var propertiesWithoutHiddenOnes = GetProperties(objectToUpdate.GetType())
            .GroupBy(prop => prop.Name)
            .Select(group => group.Aggregate(
                     (mostSpecificProp, other) => mostSpecificProp.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(other.DeclaringType) ? mostSpecificProp : other))
```